# Flask send_file return empty or blank file

Tags: python, flask

I want to return and get a .xlsx file from a server, and I use the `send_file` method in the flask library:

```
 try:        
     print(filepath)
     return send_file(filepath, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='Controle_Fiches_Appui.xlsx')
  except Exception as e:
     return str(e)
```

the filepath is good but when i try to download it from postman or a python client the return file is blank with 0 octect .. please help me

Answer (score 2):

You should use send_from_directory rather.

send_file  is just creating an empty file and giving it to you, also if its a GET request it will be cached and you will get the same file repetitively.

Why not try downloading  in incognito mode to test